# How to upload image to cloudinary with custom url and folder

Tags: node.js, cloudinary

I want to upload image to Cloudinary to specific / custom folder and to avoid the waiting for the image url response. the only problem i have is that the cloudinary engine add some value (v12094897383) to the url.

I am using Node.JS with code that store the image in custom folder with custom image name

```
        cloudinary.uploader.upload(path,
        function (result) {
            console.log(result)
        }, { public_id: 'thefolder/theimage' })
```

The url is: https://res.cloudinary.com/myaccount/image/upload/v1554136705/thefolder/theimage.png. the v1554136705 is generated by cloudinary. how can i manage that name or remove that. My goal is to get the image url before the uploading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudinary returns version to make sure you are seeing the latest image and not a cached copy. You can view the image without the version as well but that will not ensure that you are seeing the most recent image. Detailed explanation here: https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/articles/202520912-What-are-image-versions-